# Textarea text alignment

Tags: html, textarea

In my HTML form, I have the following

```
Title: <textarea cols="50" id="title" name="title" rows="4"></textarea>
```

The result is that the word "Title:" lies at the same height as the bottom of the textarea. Can I make it lie at the middle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment to middle.

```
textarea {vertical-align:middle}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/TSJkL/)

Comment: Glad you posted before I did. I have forgotten all about vertical-align.  I was jsfiddling with margins :P  Doesn't IE implement vertical align funky?

Comment: But this won't align 'Title:' as it lays out side the textarea field, wont it? How about using the <label> form field?

Comment: @vletech It does align... check out the "DEMO" link :)

Comment: @JJBeck: Ah yes so it does, sorry I was looking at the demo on my phone at the time and doesn't seem to do it on there.

Answer (score 0):

`<label>Title: <textarea cols="50" id="title" name="title" rows="4"></textarea></label>`

And then style the label element.